# Hide Finder From Dock in Sierra

Tags: finder, macos, dock

I have seen this instruction for hiding the Finder icon from MacOS:

https://github.com/jesscXC/hide-finder-trash-dock-icons

However, it doesn't seem to work on MacOS Sierra because the `DockMenus.plist` file seems to be locked and cannot be changed. Is there any other way to do this on Sierra?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer while playing with Path Finder's preferences and finding this option: "Enable Finder's "Remove from Dock" menu option. Upon clicking on it, I got the following message:

[image]

To disable SIP, however, you have to enter recovery mode. Here is more information about it on HowToGeek:

https://www.howtogeek.com/230424/how-to-disable-system-integrity-protection-on-a-mac-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: is it just me or is "changing" misspelled (on the dialog box in the image)?

Comment: Haha.. good catch!

Comment: If you dont want to use/pay Pathfinder(like me cause I prefer Commander One), you could still apply the forementioned method to remove Finder then remove Pathfinder, and still works. Thanks for the tip!